# How to retrieve cursor values in SQL server 2005 to the gridview in ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am retrieving two or more tables data based on conditions, so I am writing cursors in SQL server2005 like this:

```
create PROC [dbo].[uspCustomerInvoiceGetlist]
    @CustomerID varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT DeleteStatus,InvoiceID,CONVERT(varchar(16),CreationDate,101) + ' ' +
       CONVERT(varchar(16),CreationDate,8) as CreationDate,AccountNumber,Sum(Amount) as Amount from tblInvoiceDetails where CustomerID=@CustomerID Group By InvoiceID,CreationDate,AccountNumber,DeleteStatus
END

alter procedure uspCustomerInvoiceGetlist1(@CustomerID varchar(50)) as 
    Begin
        Declare @InvoiceID int, @Balance float
        Declare MyCur Cursor for select InvoiceID from tblInvoiceHeader where CustomerID=@CustomerID
        Open MyCur
        Fetch next from mycur into @InvoiceID
        While @@Fetch_Status=0 
        Begin
        set @Balance=(select sum(Balance) from tblInvoicePaymentDetails where CustomerId=@CustomerID and InvoiceId=@InvoiceID)
print @Balance      
if @Balance!=0

        SELECT h.DeleteStatus,h.InvoiceID,CONVERT(varchar(16),h.CreationDate,101) + ' ' +
       CONVERT(varchar(16),h.CreationDate,8) as CreationDate,h.AccountNumber,Sum(h.Amount) as Amount, @Balance as Balance from tblInvoiceDetails h inner join tblInvoicePaymentDetails p on h.CustomerID=p.CustomerID and h.InvoiceID=@InvoiceID
  Group By h.InvoiceID,h.CreationDate,h.AccountNumber,h.DeleteStatus
else
SELECT DeleteStatus,InvoiceID,CONVERT(varchar(16),CreationDate,101) + ' ' +
       CONVERT(varchar(16),CreationDate,8) as CreationDate,AccountNumber,Sum(Amount) as Amount, 0 as Balance from tblInvoiceDetails where CustomerID=@CustomerID and InvoiceID=@InvoiceID Group By InvoiceID,CreationDate,AccountNumber,DeleteStatus 

            Fetch Next From MyCUr into @InvoiceID
        End
        Close Mycur
        Deallocate Mycur
    End
```

output is correct like that (two outputs based on condition two are more)

```
 Status  InvoiceID     Date                 account no  Amount      Balance
    1   1009      06/21/2011 10:22:15       10009    450        350
```

---

```
Status  InvoiceID     Date                 account no   Amount      Balance
1   1010       06/21/2011 10:22:33        100000     690          0
```

But I can bind the all values (both) in grid view in ASP.NET 2.0. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Front End, You will get Two DataTable.
You just Combine those two DataTable into a Single One.
And Bind the DataTable with the GridView.
Merge like this:

```
   dt1.Merge(dt2);        //dt1 is the DataTable 1 and dt2 is the DataTable 2
```

Get the Set of Tables as DataSet and Merge using For Loop: I have given code below:

```
  DataTable dtmerge = new DataTable();
  for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)             // ds is the DataSet
  {
      dtmerge.Merge(ds.Tables[i]);
  }
```

Comment: suppose two are more tables displayed based on conditions how it possible sir

Comment: you get all the DataTable as you want to merge and follow the same thing.